# asp mvc 4. Get current model in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my action I need to delete some rows from database. But if exception is thrown, I need to return View with current model:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            mDataMgr.DeleteUnit(id);
        }
        catch (DataManagerException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Error == DataManagerError.UnitHasMaps)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Unit has maps");
                UnitRegionsViewModel regionsVM = new UnitRegionsViewModel()
                {
                    Regions = mDataMgr.UnitRegions(id),
                    UnitId = id
                };

                return View("View", regionsVM);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

I have to reload my current Model from database. Is there any ways to get current Model in my action?

Comment: you mean in you want to get the model coming from delte view

Comment: No. If exception is thrown, I want to render same view with same model. Without queries to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "current model".  Web pages are "stateless".  Once a page is rendered, all information about that page is gone, including its model.  One would normally post the model back to the controller if they want to get that information.

You could certainly serialize your model to hidden fields in the page, then accept that model as a parameter to your Delete method.  However, if any of that information is sensitive, this is not something you should do.

Comment: This is a correct answer. However, if you do go with hidden fields in the page, remember that you still can't trust those fields if they ever get posted back to the server (even if they are not sensitive). I remember a problem with one web site on Slahdot awhile back where the site put the user's credit card number (already authorized) in a hidden field. At that point, the user could switch the card number to be any number and the server just trusted it. So...always check your inputs! (@YuriMayorov)

Comment: @JasCav - I consider that sensitive.  Anything that the user themselves should not be able to be change is sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could fetch that model from the database and send it back? Since you have the Id that should be something you might do. Or a better way is let the delete Action accept the complete model. That way you can just return it if delete fails without fetching from the DB? Or, your delete method in your repository should send back a complete model if delete fails? All can be done.